# Is `map` in Haskell lazy?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, higher-order-functions

I've been working through Graham Hutton's Programming in Haskell. It states that

> the function `map` applies a function to all elements of a list

OK, makes sense. Certainly matches what I know about map from other languages.

One of the exercises is to implement `all :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool`.

There are times where a naive implementation may loop infinitely if not done lazily. For example `all (<10) [1..]`. So my first implementation was:

```hs
all p []       = True
all p (x:xs)   | not (p x) = False
               | otherwise = all' p xs
```

But then I thought about trying with function composition of `map` and `and` to see what a non terminating programme in Haskell would do:

```hs
all' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
all' p = and . map p
```

To my surprise, `all' (<10) [1..]` quickly returned `False`. I actually expected `map` to attempt to create an infinite list before `and` was applied - something like `and [p x | x <- xs, p x]`.

This terminating behaviour would imply that `map` is in fact creating something similar to a stream which `and` is processing. Is map in fact lazy (and hence the description wrong) or have I misunderstood something else in my second implementation?

Comment: list comprehension is lazy as well, so `and [p x | x <- xs]` will terminate from the moment there is a `False` in the list. If you use `and [p x | x <- xs, p x]` will not terminate on an infinite list, since you filter with `p x`, and thus only will return `True`s in the list.

Comment: In Haskell, you should assume that everything is lazy unless there's evidence/documentation otherwise.

Comment: @LouisWasserman good to know. Great tip - thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is `map` in fact lazy (and hence the description wrong) or have I misunderstood something else in my second implementation?

`map` is lazy. It will not eagerly apply the function to each item. In fact all expressions are lazy in the sense that `map f x` remains `map f xs` unless the value is needed.

If we evaluate `map f xs`, and we need for example the third element, it will not determine `f x1` if we are not interested in the *value* of the first element.

List comprehension is lazy as well. Indeed, if we work with:

```
and [p x | x <- xs]
```

it will terminate from the moment one of the items `x` in `xs` has `False` as `p x`. If you however add a filter `p x`, it will only emit `True`s, indeed:

```
[p x | x <- xs, p x]
```

will only yield `True`, since we already filter on the fact that `p x` should be `True`, and the `and` on a *infinite* list of `True`s will never terminate, since `and` will keep looking for a `False` value.

Comment: Incredibly useful. Thank you!